How to use WindowsAPI LoadIcon() with C#
I want to create a window using WindowsAPI in C#.
I need to call LoadIcon, a WindowsAPI, when setting hIcon property.
However, I want to use my icon.
So, how do I call LoadIcon to load my icon in C#?

我想用C#调用WindowsAPI创建窗口。
我需要在设置hIcon属性时调用LoadIcon这个WindowsAPI。
但是，我想使用我自己的图标。
我如何使用LoadIcon加载我自己的图标？

I used the Vanara library to call the WindowsAPI.
User32.WNDCLASS wndcls = new()
{
    hInstance = hInstance,
    lpszClassName = windowClassName,
    lpszMenuName = string.Empty,
    hbrBackground = Gdi32.GetStockObject(Gdi32.StockObjectType.WHITE_BRUSH),
    cbClsExtra = 0,
    cbWndExtra = 0,
    style = User32.WindowClassStyles.CS_HREDRAW | User32.WindowClassStyles.CS_VREDRAW,
    //hIcon = User32.LoadIcon(nint.Zero, User32.IDI_APPLICATION),
    hCursor = User32.LoadCursor(nint.Zero, User32.IDC_ARROW),
    lpfnWndProc = MainWindowProc,
};
User32.RegisterClass(wndcls);

How should I set the hIcon property?

我使用了Vanara库调用WindowsAPI。
我应该如何设置hIcon属性？

"I want to create a window using WindowsAPI in C#." why? Why not use WinForms or WPF?
